# Will update trigger call again and again when Update the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to make update trigger. My doubt is, when I create trigger that will change the value of same table. So it will change again?

For example:

Table name is Item

```
ItemNo ItemName  cost SellPrice
--------------------------------
101     xxx      10   12
102     xxx      12   17
103     xxx      15   19
104     xxx      17   20
```

by using update trigger I will change the cost into 99 when User update the cost.

So once it's updated into 99, will Update trigger call again?

Comment: No.  The `update` within the trigger does not re-trigger the trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok thank you bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of trigger recursion is controlled by the [`RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` database option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options). It is `OFF` by default.